# What is the correct way to use the same form two times in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a form that I use to create an event from the event dedicated CRUD, and from my planning route:

In my EventController.php, create route:

```
$form = $this->createForm(EvenementType::class,$event);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $event = $form->getData();
    $entityManager->persist($event);
    $entityManager->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('parametres.evenements');
}
```

In my PlanningController.php, index route:

```
$formEvent = $this->createForm(EvenementType::class,$evenement);
$formEvent->handleRequest($request);
if ($formEvent->isSubmitted() && $formEvent->isValid()) {
    $evenement = $formEvent->getData();
    $entityManager->persist($evenement);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

I believe this behaviour should only belong in the EventController in a store route, but I'm unsure. Could someone indicate me the right way to do it?

Comment: Create another class `EvenementTypeHandler` that has this logic in it. In your controller call the class.

Comment: Where's the error? Because you can use one form in multiple controllers..

Comment: There is no error, only what I believe is a bad practice, and I would want to be corrected.